# Creating new Articles in Modx Revo doesn't work

Tags: modx

Installation info

Modx: Revolution 2.3.1-pl (traditional)
Articles: 1.7.9-pl
Quip: 2.3.3-pl

Articles seems to be installed in package management.
When I right click a document in the tree menu and click 'Create Articles here', the browser redirects to:
http://www.example.com/manager/?id=166&a=resource/create&class_key=ArticlesContainer&parent=166&context_key=web

However, the right pane of the manager remains blank. If I click the resource again, the page is still a regular document instead of a new articles container.

The error logs shows absolutely nothing.

My question is twofold:

1: How are you supposed to debug a situation like this?
2: What could be causing this?

Comment: It does not seem that ModX Articles has been updated in a long time.

Answer (score 0):

is "example.com" you changing the URL in your question? - if not I'd say that you edited your .htaccess file & forgot to change the "example.com" domain. [though you should be having all kinds of weird problems then!]

Otherwise, try the normal Modx troubleshooting, clear modx & browser caches, disable css & js compression - the right pane is a big symptom of this. [though I haven't seen that issue in a while]. try to update to the latest Modx 2.3.2 [I think] - finally, permissions, the manager can act pretty strange if file permissions have been fiddled with. [assets/components is a big gotcha - make sure the webserver can access [R/W] it]

To debug, you can turn up your logging level to 3 [info] or 4 [debug] ~ though that may be of limited help. The manager is pretty heavy on the javascript so a browser inspector will help [using the network and console tools]

Comment: example.com is just the suggested domain to use for links here. not mine.

i asked how to debug modx if the built in error logger doesn't report anything. All caching options were disabled, cache manually and via the manager removed, chmodded articles and the transport to 777 just to see if it solves anything. uninstalled, installed and re-installed articles. set log level to 4.

Still. Blank page, and empty error log when clicking 'add articles here'.

How are you supposed to debug this without any error reporting nor debug info??